# Extracting information from auto correlation signal

Tags: autocorrelation

I have an auto correlation signal that looks like this:

[image: AUTOCORRELATION]

This is an autocorrelation graph of a single column taken from a certain image using a CCD camera.
You can see the autocorrelation strength vs. the delay / drag (in pixels).
I can see that the high-frequency spikes sit on top of a low-frequency curve.

**My question is:
what is the meaning of all the sharp spikes in the graph and the spacing between the spikes?
Do the spikes represent real high-frequency periodicity in the image or they represent a different phenomena?
What is the meaning of the low frequency curve?**

Thank you very much for your time and efforts,
Shai Yefet

Comment: What is the length of the column?

Comment: I don't understand what's on the x-axis of your graph. I thought it was the lag in pixels as autocorrelation graph would have.

Comment: Hi, it is indeed the lag in pixels it is just not centered at zero. Look at the peak of the graph it at approximately at 980, so just subtract 980 from all the values in the x-axis and you will get the lag. Thanks!

Comment: There nothing on this graph. No noticeable correlation. The peaks are just artifacts of sampling frequency